# how to make disk partition in ubuntu after installing ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

I installed ubuntu in my pc.now my pc have only one partition.i like to know how to make disk partition in ubuntu after installing ubuntu ?

Comment: please give answer

Comment: Refer this answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/98623/63025 ,And to Mods possible duplicate.

Comment: When you set up your disk partion when you installed Ubuntu did you leave any space or does your one partition take up the whole drive?

Answer (score 1):

You can try gparted, but partitioning a system that is already installed can destroy it. For best results, run the installation again, and partition the drive from there.

Comment: by running installation again, any chance for damage in data?

Comment: It will usually clear all data. The reason to do it is that re-partitioning has a chance of deleting important data, so by re-installing you know at least the system will work afterward. You need to back up your data either way. The answer tijybba linked to is probably better than mine actually. I try to avoid partitioning so I don't know what the chances are of breaking the system.